# get_terms parent for current product only

Tags: posts, taxonomy, single, terms

I wish someone can give me a clue.

I am actually displaying all product category (product_cat taxonomy) on single page products, displaying also childs regarding the product itself.

For instance: Product-A has Cat1-parent > Cat1-child1, Cat1-child2 => The code display them properly but also will display any other Parent Category that belongs to an another existing product.... result I get an extra parent category displaying with no childs.

So Id like to display only parent categories that belongs to the product itself.

I think I am missing some knowledge in the beginning of the code with the get_terms function

```
$parents = get_terms( 'product_cat' , array( 'parent' => 0 ) );

foreach( $parents as $parent ):

echo '<div class="parent '.$parent->slug.'">' . $parent->name . '</div>';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`get_terms`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) relates to getting all the terms of a taxonomy.  [`get_the_terms`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/) grabs all the terms related to the post.

The problem is that it sounds like you only want to return those terms which are parent categories, not the children, and `get_the_terms` does not pass an arguments array.

```
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' );

foreach ( $terms as $term ){
    if ( $term->parent == 0 ) {
        echo '<div class="parent '.$term->slug.'">' . $term->name . '</div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: What to do if I only want to return just child terms, No parent only child. Please give me an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the lesson. I understand better now. I just changed to my term name and inserted in my full function: 
`$parents = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' );`

`foreach ( $parents as $parent ):`
   `if ( $parent->parent == 0 ) {`
        `echo '<div class="parent '.$parent->slug.'">' . $parent->name . '</div>';`
   `}`

You helped me a lot. Thank you!